# doctrine with mamp?

Tags: php, doctrine, mamp

i want to use doctrine with my mamp.

but according to doctrine's documentation it requires php version 5.2.3 or greater.

i've checked my current version in mamp with phpinfo(), it says i've got version 5.2.11.

how can i get mamp to work with doctrine? i have never upgraded php engine manually.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem? Doctrine needs 5.2.3, you have 5.2.11.

11 > 3, isn't it?

It will work ...

I think you just confused "5.2.11" with "5.2.1.1" (which doesn't even exist).

Comment: oh yeah, i was confused! thought it meant 5.2.30 and if it was 3 they meant they would use 5.2.03. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just start using it.

You will not use all the features of Doctrine, and not all features require PHP 5.2.3. I have done quite a lot of projects with Doctrine 1.2 and PHP 5.1.9. Sometimes small functions are missing (like `spl_object_hash` for example), but it's easy to replace them with custom one.

Comment: He actually has a later version of PHP than 5.2.3. So that won't be a problem.